# Accusative or dative for verbs of movement

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

My doubt is with respect to this sentence (in perfect)

> Er ist zum Büro gegangen.

My teacher taught me that we have to use the verb *sein* as helping verb whenever there is a movement. However, why do we use a dative preposition *zu + dem* rather than an accusative preposition *in + das*? Isn't the verb *gehen* an accusative verb?
What is wrong with the following sentence?

> Er ist ins Büro gegangen.

Comment: Since your question isn't really about the perfect tense, I amended the question. For example in present tense, it's the same thing: "Ich gehe zum/ins Büro."

Comment: Wenn er zum Büro geht, geht er nicht notwendig auch hinein - vielleicht bleibt er im Sekretariat hängen? "Ins Büro gehen" sagt, er geht auch hinein.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with either sentence.

> Er ist zum Büro gegangen

focusses more on the way from his home to the office building, or from his living room to his study or whatever is appropriate to the situation, while

> Er ist ins Büro gegangen

focusses mainly on either his departure (e.g. from home) or his arrival at the office.

Comment: So is it accepted to use dative preposition to an object when the verb is accusative?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that part of your question. Each preposition demands a case, i.e. the noun (phrase) the preposition refers to has to be in that case. "Zu" demands dative. There are prepositions that allow more than one case.  "In", for instance, allows both dative and accusative: dative for a *place* (der Mann sitzt *im* Büro) and accusative for a direction (der Mann geht *in das* Büro).

Answer (score 8):

Both sentences are correct, the meaning is a little bit different.
I'd translate it as

1. He went to the office. (Er ist zum Büro gegangen.)
2. He went into the office. (Er ist ins Büro gegangen.)

Answer (score 4):

Gehen per se is not an accusative verb and it is not limited to one preposition only. You can use in, zu, vor, durch, aus, etc with it. Some make sense with Büro and some don't (mit). Which to use depends on what you want to say... just as the other answers pointed out. 
For completion I'd like to mention that also this is technically possible:

> Er geht im Büro.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this. Thank you for the answer, much appreciated. I am having a test this Sunday at Goethe Institut and this information came just in the right time. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'd like to point out, because I think it might not be clear to every learner, that "Er geht im Büro" means that he is walking inside the office, rather than going there.

Comment: I dont under stand why "er geht im Buro" is correct. The rule is if a präposition is a wechseln, we ask wo oder wohin. If wo is the appropriate question use dative, wohin use accusative. So, wohin geht er? Er get ins Büro.

Comment: @Rodney Monsanto Tabernero: _Er geht im Büro_ is “technically possible”, just as Emanuel said; it means something different from _Er geht ins Büro_, however – namely, that he is walking inside the office.

Comment: I asked my german friend and he told me "er geht im buro" makes no sense. He is walking inside the office is "er geht im büro herum".