# When to use which preposition with "gehen"? "in" vs "zu"

Tags: grammar, preposition

I've always been confused about this:

> Ich gehe zur Haltestelle Einsteinstraße.
>   Ich gehe in die Bank.

Is there a rule on when to use *zu*/*in* with *gehen*?

Comment: [This](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/5556/1224) will answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answers in the similar question linked in Em1's comment indicate correctly, the meaning differs:

**In** is used to indicate that you actually enter some place/building instead of just walking to the location and stopping outside (for example to wait there for someone).

> Ich gehe ins Kino.

I probably intend to see a film there.

> Ich gehe zum Kino und warte dort auf euch.

There are several bars and a café there, I'll be there but probably won't enter before you arrive there too.

As always, there are exceptions, especially with regard to idiomatic expressions. For example, to ask a kid where it attends school, both versions are in use (usage varies among regions):

> Wo gehst du zur Schule?
>
> Wo gehst du in die Schule?
>
> In welche Schule gehst du?

Note that none of these ask for the way to school, it's just about which school the child attends.

So, to come back to your examples:

You usually wouldn't use **in** with bus stop because there isn't any building to enter. You may use both with the bank, depending on what you wish to express - **in** if you want to stress the fact that you enter the building, **zur** if you just go there without entering (e.g. to withdraw money from an ATM accessible from outside).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation.  After reading this I feel like I've finally understood something I was struggling with for a long time.