# Difference between `in der Stadt` and `in die Stadt`

Tags: preposition, learning, standard-german

Taking the following example:

- Ich gehe in der Stadt.
- Ich gehe in die Stadt.

I couldn't understand when to say `in die Stadt` and when to say `in der Stadt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ich gehe in **der** Stadt" is for when you are **already in** the city and walking around there opposed to 
 "Ich gehe in **die** Stadt" is for when you walk to the city.

Direct translation:

> Ich gehe in die Stadt
>   *I go to the city*
>
> Ich gehe in der Stadt
>   *I am walking in the city*

As @Ralf Joerres stated `Ich gehe in der Stadt` is gramatically not entirely correct, as the verb `gehen` with the meaning of `to walk somewhere` always asks for a `where to?`

So as @Takkat stated, if you don't want to change the meaning of the sentence, you could say `Ich gehe in der Stadt herum`, which means to walk around in the city.

Comment: We may have to add that the variant *Ich gehe in der Stadt* though grammatically correct still is incomplete in everyday's usage. If we hear a foreigner say so we immediately think he did not get the gender right. We generally add some precision: e.g. *Ich gehe in der Stadt herum* - *Ich gehe in der Stadt spazieren* - *Ich gehe in der Stadt auf und ab*....

Comment: now it is clear

Comment: but can we also say `Ich gehe zur Stadt` ??

Comment: Yes, in this case `Ich gehe in die Stadt` and `Ich gehe zur Stadt` are both correct, yet the focus of "zur" and "in die" are a little different. Refering to https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/accusative-or-dative-for-verbs-of-movement

Comment: @Takkat: Ich halte 'ich gehe in der Stadt' für grammatikalisch nicht korrekt, denn 'gehen' als Fortbewegungsverb verlangt grundsätzlich eine Direktivergänzung (= wohin?), wovon nur abgewichen wird bei Weglassung einer mitgedachten Ergänzung: geh endlich! (= geh weg) und in anderen Bedeutungen als denen eines Fortbewegungsverbs (das Radio geht nicht mehr, der Teig muss 1 Std. gehen...) und in Kombination mit Infinitiven ('einkaufen gehen' als Tätigkeitsbezeichnung) oder Präfixen (hin- und hergehen, heimgehen) und ähnlichen Spezialfällen. Alles andere sehe ich genauso.

Comment: Dann hat Joey jetzt ganz viel Material, wie er seine Antwort mit einem [edit] verbessern kann ;)